# PostgreSQL with OSX Mavericks and Psycopg2 not able to connect with Django Localhost on Mac

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql, psycopg2

I am currently running:

```
Postgresql 9.3.1
psycopg2==2.5.2
OSX Mavericks 10.9.2
Python 2.7.6
Django 1.5.4
```

I am trying to launch my Django App to test, but am getting a configuration error with psycopg2.  This is the error.  It was working before upgrading the OSX to Mavericks, and now I can't get it to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/flapsta2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/flapsta2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: Navigate to your /usr/local/lib/ and find out which version of libpq you currently have. Once you know which version you're running you can symlink it using 
`ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.<your_version_here>.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

That worked for me when I had a similar issue although I'm not a mac wizard so don't kill me if it won't work!

Comment: @serakiel thank you for your suggestion.  It helped me get the answer to the fix.  I posted the exact fix below. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

To get this working I had to symlink the **most recent** `libpq.5.dylib` file from my `PostgreSQL` directory to my `/usr/lib/libqp.5.dylib` file, and `PostgreSQL` and `Psycopg2` finally work!

**@serakiel**, thank you for your suggestion, that helped lead to the answer.

Here is the command that I ran in Terminal to fix the issue:

```
sudo ln -fs /library/postgresql/9.3/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Comment: On El Capitan, you will need to disable SIP first. See [here](http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away). Best to turn it back after adding the link and seeing that it works.